# How to create a dynamic object based on different entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created two fetch methods

1. to get Invoice Details
2. to get Sales order details

I got the result set as list.
I need to create common method to send an email (the email method should be generic) by passing the invoice, Sales, etc. arguments to send an email, without creating a common entity is there any other way to solve this.
Can any one help me out?

```
    List<Tableinvoiceheader> inv_List=rpc.getInvoiceDetails();
    List<TableSalesorder> sales_List=rpc.getsalesDetails();
 --email trigger method
     mailObj.sendemailMessage(From,to,subject,body,"(Generic object)");
```

Generic object can be either salesdetails or invoicedetails

Comment: you can use `Object` class as parameter. Then cast it into your desired object class.

Comment: I need to add flag in sendemailMessage () and then based on the flag i need to cast my object .But is there any other way ?

Comment: You could check for type, EG: `obj instanceof Tableinvoiceheader`

Comment: if you want to send both objects then you can go with `Map<String, Object>`, If one at a time `Object` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by not creating a Generic Entity.  Here is one way:

You will first need to create a java interface for converting an object to text suitable for email.  Let us call this Interface Email

**A sample prototype quality code:**

```
public interface TextForEmail {

String getText();
}
```

Your `InvoiceDetail` and `SalesDetail` classes should implement this interface.  Their implementations should take their respective object properties and convert it into text suitable for email text.

Your sendMailMessage signature needs to accept the interface as a parameter and that is the Generic Object.  You could also do a List of the interface if you choose so.

You should then invoke sendMailMessage passing the SalesDetails or InvoiceDetails or both (depending on how you implemented your sendMailMessage as your "Generic Object", and what went into your Generic Object List) as parameter(s).

Your sendMailMessage implementation will then need to call the **getText** method to get the text and append it to the email as appropriate.

Hope this helps.